# Bootstrap grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem about container class in bootstrap.
I created the theme (which is in below picture) with `col-md-4` grid system for the head of article.

Picture: http://imgim.com/boot1.png

But I wanted to give background-color each of the "head of article" div with extra class.
then I got this (below picture)

Picture: http://imgim.com/boot2.png

container class has own padding (which is 15px from left and right).
In this case when I apply background color, the div colors overflowed the outside.

bootstrap is the good way to make responsive websites, but in this case
I'm having problems with theme design.

Any idea about to fix this?

Comment: Your images can not be found.

Answer (score 3):

`padding is the space between the content and the border`

seeing through your image files you might have coded something like this

`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 clrclass">some content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 clrclass">some content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 clrclass">some content</div>
    </div>
</div>`

instead use div class inside col-sm-3 like this

`<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="clrclass">some content</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="clrclass">some content</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="clrclass">some content</div></div>
    </div>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <style>
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
                <img src="http://localhost:1038/Images/login.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Login.jpg" width="100%"/>
            </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                       <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-lg-offset-10 col-md-offset-10 col-sm-offset-9 col-xs-offset-4">
                                <img src="http://localhost:1038/Images/sahil.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Sahil.jpg" width="100%"/>

                             </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-pull-5 col-md-pull-5 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col" style="background-color:red;">
                                <form name="form1" method="post" class="form-group">
                                <div class="label">Username</div>
                                <input type="email"  class="form-control" />
                                <div class="label">Password</div>
                                <input type="password"  class="form-control" />
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="form-control btn-primary" />
                                </form>
                          </div>
                   </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```